# Find a vector that lies in the plane determined by a line and a point and is perpendicular to that line

Tags: calculus, vectors, products, cross-product

I need to use the triple cross product to find a vector that lies in the plane determined by

the point (1, 0, 2) and the line $\frac {x}{2}=\frac {y+1}{3}=\frac {z-2}{-1}$ , and is perpendicular to the line

Comment: Define "determined."

Comment: The equation of the plane is determined by taking 2 points on the line and the third given right?  The question just wants us to find a vector perpendicular to the given line and that also lies in the plane that passes through the line and the point.  Hopefully that clears it up.  I just don't understand how I use the triple cross product to find it since I was given only a point and a line but no vectors

Comment: It shouldn’t be too hard to find two points on the line, if that’s what you need.

Comment: as amd suggested, find two points that belong to the line and there you have tree points and three vectors

Comment: That totally makes sense.  Now that I have 3 vectors how do I make sure that the cross product is in the same plane and perpendicular to the given line?

Comment: By “a vector that lies in the plane,” do you mean a point on the plane or a vector that’s parallel to the plane (and orthogonal to the line’s direction)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $A(1,0,2)$. You can simply  determine the coordinates of the intersection $H$ of the line and the plane through $A$ perpendicular to the line: you'll then can take the vector $\overrightarrow{AH}$.

As the line has $\;\vec u(2,3,-1)$ as a directing vector, an equation of the plane through $A$  perpendicular to the line is
$$2x+3y-z=2\cdot 1+3\cdot 0-1\cdot 2=0.$$
Can you continue?